# Stop CSS hover / unhover on parent element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm not sure how to phrase this to be honest.

I have a navigation bar which exposes sub menus when hovered lets say

```
#navigation:hover #submenu {visibility: visible}
```

within the submenu I have a close button which I when clicked should stop the hover on the navigation element. But not remove it for future hovers.

How would I get around this problem ?

Comment: So it should collapse the submenu?

Comment: Can you post your html and CSS?

Comment: for manage this type of interaction you should manage via javascript.
 if you post a fiddle is easier understand the structure.

Comment: Here is a fiddle of what I am trying to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/v8jroxvx/

sorry for the vague nature of the question, I'm not very sure on the jargon to use x

Comment: So are you trying to achieve: Upon hovering the navigation bar, the links are displayed, when your mouse leaves the navigation the navigation is still visible however, clicking close. Closes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:active` selector.

```
#test:hover #grapes {
    display: block;
}
#grapes {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    position: relative;
}
#fubar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
#fubar:active + ul {
    display: none;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8jroxvx/4/)**

PS: I interchanged the `ul` and `#fubar` elements' positions to get desired solution using adjacent sibling selector.

Comment: Interesting, what about compatibility ? Is this working great in IE 8-9 ?

Comment: @enguerranws yup.. should work as I am not using css3 here. :)

Comment: Yes but IE and some others don't trigger / understand :active pseudo-class on all html elements.

Comment: @enguerranws works fine for IE8+ [MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, being explicit is the answer. `hover` and `toggleFade` are useful shortcuts to things, but when you need to do something more complex (like have a manual intervention in the `hover` or `fade` handling) then you're better using an explicit, expanded form, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v8jroxvx/1/

```
$('#test').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#grapes').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}).on('mouseleave', function() { $('#grapes').stop(true, true).fadeOut(); })

$('#fubar').click(function()
{
    $('#grapes').fadeOut();
})
```

I am explicitly saying *on mouse enter, fade the nav in* and *on mouse leave, fade the nav out* and in the case of clicking the close button, I am explicitly saying *when I clicick #grapes, forcefully fade the nav out*.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this

```
    $hoveredContainer.css('pointer-events', 'none');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $hoveredContainer.css('pointer-events', 'auto')
    }, 10);
```

Where $hoveredContainer is a variable containing the jQuery element that is being hovered.

What that code does is "unhover" the element for a split second.

It works for drop downs when the mouse is over the 'expanded' area where the selection is being made.